# How to specify the size of char column in Hibernate annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class like this, with a `String` field that can contain a lot of text:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "books")
public class Book  {
  ...
  //long description - exceeds char(255) limit
  private String description;
  ...
}
```

By default Hiberante creates a `character varying(255)` column for that field, which is too small. How do I get it to make a column for that particular field, for instance, `text` or `varchar(1000)`?

Comment: I think this link will be very useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135905/columndefinition-text-for-all-types-of-databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by setting `columnDefinition` as `TEXT`.

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "books")
public class Book  {
  ...
  @Column(name = "description", columnDefinition="TEXT") 
  private String description;
  ...
}
```