# limit of long text datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used longtext data type, in which I need to keep appending the newly comming text.

Is there any limit when this database item get saturated ?

Later on fetch this record value for getting list of words in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13932834/1243426

Answer (score 2):

According to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html), maximum length of LONGTEXT is 4,294,967,295 (2^32) chars.