# What is the max length for char type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a BLOB into some text format. So I wrote a query like this, which works fine:

```
SELECT CAST(key_initiatives AS CHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 )  AS key_init 
FROM OBJSETTING_FOCUS_ON_CUSTOMER
```

If I try to create a column with a char type which does not allow more than 250 characters, when the source data allows 1000 or even 15000 characters, what will happen?

I am using MySQL GUI v9.50.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT maximum storage sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750/tinytext-text-mediumtext-and-longtext-in-mysql-maximum-storage-sizes)

The data type and the maximum size,

```
      Type | Maximum length
-----------+-------------------------------------
  TINYTEXT |           255 (2 8−1) bytes
      TEXT |        65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
  LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

Comment: Hi Ravi but here I took char which doesn't mentioned above .Is text and char are same .please suggest

Comment: Hi ravi please clarify my doubt Please