# mysql | What is difference between SET and TEXT field types?

Tags: mysql

What is difference between SET and TEXT column types?
I know that maximum length of SET column type is 64 elements. If I will use TEXT column type can I avoid this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set.html) and [`text`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html) are two completely different things.

A `set` allows you to specify which values (up to 64) are allowed in a column, and input values that contain any unique combination of these values. `text`, on the other hand, is just a **really** long string.

Comment: What is faster for FIND_IN_SET command. Search in numerical SET or search in the numerical TEXT field???

Comment: Depends on the specific data, of course, but as a rule of thumb, using a numerical `SET` should be considerably faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can avoid this limit (64 elements), But `TEXT` type has its limits:

```
Maximum length (TEXT type): 65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
```

For more information about *maximum storage sizes* types, see there:

[TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT maximum storage sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750/tinytext-text-mediumtext-and-longtext-maximum-storage-sizes)