# What happens when I convert a TEXT column to a MEDIUMTEXT column?

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a table with a `TEXT` column, and there is data in it, what happens when I change that column from `TEXT` to `MEDIUMTEXT`, and is there something that I should be aware of or avoid?

Could there be any corruption or loss of data?

---

Note:

- I'm converting from a smaller to a larger type. There should not be any truncation.
- I'm aware of the lengths of the different types.
- What I want to know is **what happens during conversion** and **how does that affect data**?

Answer (score 1):

You will have more characters allowed by row :

```
      Type | Maximum length
-----------+-------------------------------------
  TINYTEXT |           255 (2 8−1) bytes
      TEXT |        65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
  LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

Comment: Since when is 16MiB less than 64KiB?

Comment: @Till I'm converting from a smaller to a larger type. There should not be any truncation.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Indeed there will be no changes in your data.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750/tinytext-text-mediumtext-and-longtext-maximum-storage-sizes) for maximum sizes for different column types. Since you're changing from smaller to bigger type, you don't need to worry about truncation. It's a safe operation. Also, you very probably have no index on that column, so not much to worry about there either.