# 1265 data truncated for column at row 1 after few values

Tags: php, mysql

hello i am trying to add data to mysql column but after some data has been input it throws subject mentioned error

The structure is 
[image]

the column data format is 
[image]

Comment: You'll probably need something bigger than a `tinytext` for that column, tinytext can only contain 255 bytes

Comment: which format suits the best  if i have to query the column as well and the data will be quite a bit ?

Comment: have a look at this question for the available sizes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750/tinytext-text-mediumtext-and-longtext-maximum-storage-sizes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data is being truncated because it exceeds the 255 byte limit of a `tinytext` column. You'll need to use a column type that supports more data:

```
      Type | Maximum length
-----------+-------------------------------------
  TINYTEXT |           255 (2 8−1) bytes
      TEXT |        65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
  LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

(from [TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT maximum storage sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750/tinytext-text-mediumtext-and-longtext-maximum-storage-sizes))