# TYPO3 DCE / Content Module

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-extensions

I built a website with TYPO3 and to build individual content modules I use the DCE extension. - [DCE](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dce)

I created some basic input fields:
[image: Simple input]

If I want to use the module and if I insert some text everythink is working fine. But if i use chars like --  ö ä ü --  I will get following error:

[image]

[image]

Problem is, here in Germany every second word has a char like that.

I can't find any kind of mistake or error from my side.
I doesn't matter what for type of input I am using (simple input, text area or RTE)

I already created a complete new TYPO3 installation. But here I get the same error. I also looked into the php-files. But my knowledge is not specific enough to make some changes there.

Hope someone can give me help or some tips.

Thank you
mando

Comment: Where do you enter umlauts? In the fieldname (variable) or as content of a field?

Comment: Hey Paul, as content in a field.

Comment: Does it work for other records like tt_content?

Comment: Have a look at your database: what charset has that field?
in TYPO3 everywhere the charset should be UTF8-anything.
in mySQL that could be differnt on every level: connection, database, table, field

Comment: When try to insert some text with tt_content (standard module) i will get these warning: 1: These fields of record 22 in table "tt_content" have not been saved correctly: bodytext! The values might have changed due to type casting of the database. And alls chars like äöü will change in to a "?".

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ all fields have the typo varchar(255) in the database.

Comment: not the type but the collation (something like utf8_general, latin1_swedish, ...)

Comment: The server connection collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: and what about the field itself?

Comment: The TYPO3 error message, "These fields of record 22 in table "tt_content" have not been saved correctly: bodytext! The values might have changed due to type casting of the database", appeared in a related problem, [TYPO3 RTE: Saving mathematical/greek symbols doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585582/typo3-rte-saving-mathematical-greek-symbols-doesnt-work).