# PHP7-MariaDB Insert data form

Tags: php, html, mariadb

I'm a newbie so please be patient I'd like to create an HTML form that adding DATA to MariaDB. Just basic! But I'm not able to

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>
<title>PAGINA CARICAMENTO DATI</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Inserisci i dati richiesti</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="input.php">
        <tr>
          <td>Nome</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cognome</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="surname" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Città</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="city" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
          name="submit" value="Sent"></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

AND the PHP part is:

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='password';
$database='esempio';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

printf($name);
printf($surname);
printf($city);

$sql="INSERT INTO people (ID,Name,Surname,City)VALUES(default,$name,$surname,$city)";
printf($sql);
if(!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)){ 
printf("Errore: %s\n",mysqli_error($connection));
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

MAriaDB have 4 columns:

1. ID Index    int(11)             No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT  Change Change
       Drop Drop
2. Name    tinytext    utf8_general_ci         No  None            Change Change   Drop    Drop
3. Surname     tinytext    utf8_general_ci No  None
               Change Change   Drop Drop
4. City    tinytext    utf8_general_ci
           No  None            Change Change   Drop Drop

Comment: What error are you receiving and on what line?

Comment: Unknown column 'pippo' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you post the line that is saying the error is occuring at

Comment: Strings need to be quoted (`default,$name,$surname,$city`). You also are open to SQL injections. You can fix both issues with parameterized queries.

Comment: @PietroOttati answer posted over 1/2 hour ago; no response. You need to comment if something is still not working and I've made a few edits to my answer below.

Comment: Please avoid posting large blocks of code. As large parts are likely not relevant, it only makes the question harder to read. Current/Expected output and data samples are also appreciated. I'd advise reading this: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Fred I'm sorry but here probably a different time zone. I was sleeping. ;)

Comment: @CmdrSharp I'm sorry but as I told at the very beginning of my post I'm a newbie in this phase everything seems important so I posted the all code. I know that is not a good thing and I'm really sorry but yesterday after 2h of test I didn't quite catch the problem so I decided to post the all code... XD I'll do better ASAP

Comment: @PietroOttati *ah si, dimenticato (scusi) sei in Italia.* Did you consult my answer below? That should have fixed it for you. If not, let me know if you are getting any errors.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Your Italian is quite good XD. Thank you so much your answer was really helpful.

Comment: @PietroOttati grazie mille! Studiare la vostra lingua per un anno adesso, e prego :-)

Comment: Studiare la vostra lingua per un anno adesso, e prego :-) --> It's better in this way. Ho studiato la vostra lingua per un anno, comunque prego. Because I think you want to say somethig like "you're welcome" just to answer my previous "thank you" don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings values require them to be quoted.

```
VALUES('','$name','$surname','$city')
```

Note: Since your ID column is an AI, remove the `default`.

However, this would require you to escape your data for 2 reasons.

- If any of those values contains characters that MySQL would complain about; *i.e.:* apostrophes.
- Open to an SQL injection.

Use a prepared statement instead.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Check for errors on the query also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

And error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

You should also check for empty inputs.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Another thing is to make sure you've made the right choice of column types. `tinytext` may not be what you want to use here, but will still work; `varchar` is usually the preferred choice when using string literals.

Consult:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html
- [TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT maximum storage sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750/tinytext-text-mediumtext-and-longtext-maximum-storage-sizes)

---

**HTML stickler:**

- `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`.

Comment: Hi @Fred -ii-  your code work perfectly, but now of course I'm going to study your link so I can Improve my code. Could you suggest any book or other sources for me? Just please considering that I really need a low level approach.

Comment: @PietroOttati This site has a lot of good things in there http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-prepared-statement.aspx and follow the other links in there.

Comment: Did it work? I'm sorry I know I have to learn so much. But Anyway I didn't mean to use an incorrect netiquette.

Comment: @PietroOttati Yes it did Pietro, grazie, tutto è molto bene ;-) benvenuto a Stack :-)