# MySQL TEXT column in load file

Tags: mysql, text

I have a table with some TEXT columns, all of them get value when I load the file into the table but the TEXT column with 100 length character does not work and shows null value. The source file is fixed width file and I have checked the character number and the proper length of the field.

Do I need to do any configuration to get a long TEXT field in the column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750/tinytext-text-mediumtext-and-longtext-maximum-storage-sizes - Check this answer.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: It is 100 character and it is just simple load file sql every thing is working but this TEXT column with 100 character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the encodings/character sets.
If the text file is e.g. `utf-8` and your text column ist e.g. `latin1` a 100 char text from the file may need more than 100 chars in the database table.

In this case you need to change the encoding or the length of the text column.

See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html