# Text truncation on MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, truncation

I have my MySQL server running on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to store 80k characters XML response into database but every time it gets truncated so only a part of original response ends up saved.

Field type is LONGTEXT. I have no problems saving same data on Windows localhost.

I have no idea what's causing this problem. Is there someone who's faced similar issue before and knows how to fix it?

Comment: The no. of characters depends on the encoding you're using. Check out this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750/tinytext-text-mediumtext-and-longtext-maximum-storage-sizes

Check what encoding you're using. If changing the encoding doesn't work, try converting the field type to blob.

Comment: @PrateekDewan I've changed field type to BLOB and now it works like a charm. Much thanks!